# ¿Cómo se llaman las primeras dos décadas del siglo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, tiempo

Yo nací en los años setenta y me casé en los noventa.

> Mis hijos nacieron en...
>
> y ahora estamos en...

Sé que no hay una respuesta única, pero ¿qué forma cómoda y correcta recomiendan para denominar las dos primeras décadas de un siglo? ¿En algún país se solucionó este vacío?

Y aprovecho de preguntar esto otro: ¿los ochenta o los *ochentas*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pues supongo que "**en la primera/segunda década del siglo**" respectivamente. A partir de ahí ya puedes usar construcciones como "en los años veinte" o "en los (años) setenta".

Tenemos el mismo problema para los años en las edades de las personas. Puedes decir que alguien tiene veintitantos o treinta y tantos años, pero no que tiene *"diecitantos"* (Ni siquiera en inglés *teenager* recoge todo el rango de la década).

**En español hasta el número dieciséis no empezamos a escribir con el mismo prefijo a los números comprendidos en una misma decena**.

Las décadas de que se compone un siglo, se expresan preferentemente utilizando los numerales cardinales que designan cada decena. Debido a la manera en la que formamos los [cardinales numerales](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB) en español no podemos nombrar los números 1-9 y 10-19 con un prefijo común, a diferencia de la manera en que podemos con los veintitantos, treinta y tantos, etc. (aunque me he columpiado un poco al llamarlo "prefijo", ya que los *dieci-* y *veinti-* se escriben con una sola palabra y el resto separado).

Por eso en los numerales sólo tenemos términos para nombrar las decenas a partir de la segunda decena: veinte, treinta, cuarenta... Date cuenta que en tu ejemplo hay una elipsis

> Yo nací en *(la década de)* los años setenta y me casé en *(la década de )* los *(años)* noventa.

y al no poder señalar la decena a la que corresponden esos años no podemos usar la construcción "En (la década de) los (años) sesenta".

Para responder a tu segunda pregunta, lo correcto es "**los ochenta**" y no "los ochenta**s**", ya que las décadas de que se compone un siglo se expresan utilizando los numerales cardinales que designan cada decena, siempre en singular.

Comment: Aprovecho la pregunta reciente [Cómo referirse a las décadas en plural](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35639/5481), donde enlazo a una artículo de fundeu, ["los veinte, y no los veintes ni los 20's'](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/decadas-ochenta-no-ochentas/), donde se confirma que " **no hay una denominación establecida para la primera década de un siglo**, por lo que se aconseja utilizar expresiones como la primera década del siglo XX o la década de 1901 a 1910 (o la década de 1900 para referirse a los años entre 1900 y 1909, pues entre 1900 y 1910 hay once años)"

Answer (score 3):

No hay problema, aunque sea menos común, llamar a los años en las primeras y segundas décadas de siglos como *los años cero* o *los años diez*

Constan usos en [España](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/audios/el-sotano/sotano-vivieron-murieron-decada-anos-cero-bandas-nacionales-primera-parte-06-01-10/661713/), [Colombia](http://icaadocs.mfah.org/icaadocs/THEARCHIVE/FullRecord/tabid/88/doc/1133754/language/en-US/Default.aspx) y [Argentina](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&ved=0CDgQFjAEOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Flatipicatango.com.ar%2Fla-tipica-lunatico-33-tango-en-los-anos-cero%2F&ei=eTiUVNjTLIiqggS86ILgCw&usg=AFQjCNFeWAImFlvMIaZPgqdSQ4N7UrOdmA&sig2=OzR0UL2UMK51khML2bwBWA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY) para *los años cero* (salen muchos ejemplos en Google, solo los pongo como ejemplo de la extensión del uso).

Curiosamente, una editorial de *El País* [reconoce](http://elpais.com/diario/2011/01/09/eps/1294558017_850215.html) *los años diez* pero no *los años cero* (pero en su discusión, lo hace claro que se entendería el uso).

*los años diez* tiene menos uso según google, pero sin duda se usa para hablar de una época del cine español (que curiosamente va de 1910 a 1921).

Imagino que ya cuando estemos en los veinte o treinta, *los años cero* sonará mejor ya que estaremos hablando de estos años más como una década entera, igual con *los años diez* que todavía no hemos acabado.

Para mí no suena muy bien *en los cero* o *en los diez*, pero sería imposible ver si disfruta de algún uso popular o incluso periodístico, porque al buscar *los cero*, aparece toda clase de página que tiene *los cero grados* o parecido, peor aún con *los diez*.

Comment: Muy interesante, gracias. Parece lógico y fácil, pero no creo que nos acostumbremos a decir _los años cero_.

Comment: ¡Interesante! Veo que también [hay quien menciona](http://www.microsiervos.com/archivo/mundoreal/lio-decadas.html) "los años 2000".