# Cómo referirse a las décadas en plural

Tags: plurales, tiempo

¿Cómo se escribe correctamente "en la época de los 80s"?
Se puede escribir 80's, con letra "los ochentas" o "en la época de los 80".

¿Qué es mejor?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es correcto usar '80 u 80s para referirnos a décadas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21801/1674)

Answer (score 4):

> Para aludir a los años que van desde 2020 hasta 2029, lo adecuado es usar formas como los años veinte o los veinte y no los años veintes, los veintes, los 20’s, la década de los 20’s, etc.

Fuente: [(Fundeu) los veinte, y no los veintes ni los 20's](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/decadas-ochenta-no-ochentas/)

El artículo enlaza a las fuentes de la RAE ([la entrada sobre "décadas"](https://www.rae.es/dpd/d%C3%A9cada)) en el siguiente párrafo:

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas precisa que cada una de las décadas (entendidas como todos los años que tienen todas las cifras iguales salvo la de las unidades: 1960 a 1969, 2020 a 2029) se representa [con el numeral en singular](https://www.rae.es/dpd/d%C3%A9cada), escrito preferiblemente en letras: los años treinta, la década de los sesenta, los noventa…

El artículo cita algunos de los errores más frecuentes y explica la forma correcta, que debería responder a tus dudas sobre si cada una de las fórmulas que citas es correcta y cual puede ser preferible sobre otras.